# Pushnotifications in windows phone app 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I want to send pushnotifications to windows phone.

string subscriptionUri = "https://hk2.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAAAqksei6yWvmlcV8RmESRNrXotwCWV0AY9PSOtmgpIo%2bNwq67tkYjG7450r%2bUKpLwxri%2bO7Re9%2f8qmZDAc3TmTlMOaONVqq9ogCKONX2oWe%2fVq%2bT9tIxEllJW3tnKJEfNM%3d";

//string subscriptionUri = "http://s.notify.live.net/u/1/hk2/H2QAAACfgMkOSS8jNp_XgLamnXFqQrk6g8L6pRJHsQxvppe8-lD4EgCu8LcwdtuDIGnY78tjyaL1lsFxLjWl5s-Sgum5tjBQMk-9emm73LJa9125iECyFCoPb5erRBRwGAgNv2o/d2luZG93c3Bob25lZGVmYXVsdA/jGFxihnYNUOIt5Q4gABT7Q/T4l1SvWZqMi_mEe4F61sx-CINOg";

in the above two  channeluris  first one is Windows RT app uri,second one is Silverlight app uri.Iam getting notification whenever silverlight app uri used.but I am not getting notification whenever windows RT app uri used.whenever 
I am sending windows RT app uri to the server then response is "OK" but not getting any notification to my device.please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you enabled toast notification? In Package.appxmanifest, Under Application tab there is "Notifications" option "Toast Capable" set it to "yes"

Comment: Iam set to "yes" in Toast capable" but not getting

Comment: Check the phone settings. if notification is ON/OFF

Comment: I received  notification working fine  .but whenever click on that the page was not redirected to my app.its not clicking

Answer (score 0):

One more possibility is the subscription uri is getting decoded at the receiving end.

Comment: then what should i do.please help me

Comment: Actually my toastmessage is string PushNotificationXML1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
           "<wp:Toast>" +
                "<wp:Text1>Hai this is pavan</wp:Text1>" +
           "</wp:Toast> " +
        "</wp:Notification>";

Comment: but whenever I received notification it doesnot show message for example "Hai This is pavan".it shoeing only "Notification"

Comment: Try this "<toast launch=\"/text to receive\">" +
    "<visual>"+
     "   <binding template=\"ToastText02\">"+
      "      <text id=\"1\">headlineText</text>"+
      "      <text id=\"2\">bodyText</text>"+
      "  </binding>"+
   " </visual>"+
"</toast>"

Comment: Please see my this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414484/push-notification-error-in-windows-phone-8-1-rt